# Backing up linux server settings / What should be backed up?

Tags: linux, redhat-enterprise-linux

I've set up two linux boxes (dedicated hosting) and I want to make a backup of the server settings on both just in case something goes wrong and I need to restore the settings.

The hosting provider and I have made changes to the following:

```
csf
iptables
php settings
/etc/resolv.conf
NFS configuration (NFS settings, /etc/exports, etc)
a few services currently running / enabled
```

1. Is there anything else that I should be taking a backup of?
2. What are the *proper* commands for backing each of these up?

Its a RHEL5 system and my application is using PHP + MYSQL. I dont know where I should pick up custom MYSQL settings from.

Comment: Nothing special about iptables here, so I removed that flag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few notes about items you mentioned:

- iptables keeps all its settings in /etc/sysconfig/iptables
- The key with php is in /etc/php.ini. Yes, a .ini file on linux. I believe it also keeps some information under /etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf, if you also have apache installed.
- /etc/resolv.conf is the file that controls where the nameserver is that the system uses.
- nfs config info is under /etc/exports
- service run state is all controlled by the status of /etc/rc.d and the links under there.

So if you back up everything under /etc as sleske mentioned, you should be good.

The one exception is that stock MySQL databases are kept in /var/lib/mysql. But if you try to back up that directory, you might run into file locking issues. So what you should do is to run `mysqldump --all-databases > your_backup_filename` and then back up your_backup_filename. To automatically run it, put it in a cronjob.

You don't mention what program you use to make php useful, maybe it's Apache? If that's the case, then you'll also probably want to back up /var/www; all Apache's documents/logs go there.

Comment: +1 Thanks for checking all the packages mentioned, I was too lazy to do that :-).

Comment: BTW: It's true that MySQL DBs are under /var/lib/mysql, but that's not really "configuration data", that's application data - the question was only about configuration data. Still, good to point it out.

Comment: Yes thanks Kevin! And sleske - any clue about 'configuration' data related to MYSQL?

Comment: Either of you guys have inputs on other settings I *should* be backing up as well?

Comment: @matt_tm: check my new paragraph on Apache.

Comment: sweet! thanks Kevin for taking the time out to explain all that...

Answer (score 4):

By convention, under Linux all configuration settings are stored in files under `/etc/` (for systemwide settings), or in dotfiles/dot-directories in the user's $HOME (for user-specific settings). Sometimes there may be stuff under `/usr/local/etc`, for apps installed under `/usr/local`.

So backing up that should be enough.

There are a few exceptions (e.g. boot manager configuration is under `/boot`, though e.g. Debian autogenerates the file from a file under /etc/ to maintain the convention), but I don't think any of the packages you list do this.

Of course, for an easy restore you should just back up the whole server (possible excluding some huge files you don't need). Why don't you just make a full backup?

Comment: umm - is there some tool that allows an easy backup / restore mechanism? Sorry, new to linux administration

Comment: No, I've never heard of one. Just backup `/etc/`and the home dirs (using `tar` or similar). A hypothetical backup/restore mechanism could not do more anyway, without special support for every program installed, which seems difficult.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into [etckeeper](http://kitenet.net/~joey/code/etckeeper/)

Comment: A good tool, but not really meant as a backup (though that's a side benefit). For "just a backup" it might be too much hassle to set up...

Comment: I'm surprised others havent run into similar issues on their server administration adventures...